# MG995 not working under 3A and 6.96V

Tags: arduino, servomotor, current

I'm trying to work with this type of servomotors, I've been having a hard time trying to supply the required current to it, these are the things that I've tried:

- First, I tried creating my own power supply with an electric transformer of 12V-1A, but it seemed that the motor was not having enough current, which doesn't make sense because they usually work with 0.7-0.9 A, and only require 3A if something is keeping them from moving (I adjusted the voltage with a lm7805). The motor was moving very slowly.
- Then I got an eliminator that supplied 12V-3A, I reduced the voltage to 6.96V with a lm350t, but when I connected a motor for a while, the lm350t started to smell like it was getting hot. I was able to read the current and it was about 2.5A. When I tried to connect it again the motor was not moving at all. I used another MG995 that I have, which was also not moving. I don't know what to do at this point, I'm currently working with a Arduino UNO, here's the code:

````
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myServo;

void setup() {
  myServo.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
  myServo.write(180);

}
```
````